# How to check and print discord timestamp reaction?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

super noobs here, I just made my first autoreply greeting bot with online JS guide, and I'm getting very excited. Now I want to add another function to my bot.

let's say I have 3 friends Pete, Mickey and Hana that reacted to my message, and I want to know who is the fastest by getting their reaction timestamp. What I have is the message ID.

Something like if I typed `!checktime 621405178553516409` and the bot reply is:

```
Pete 2.147 seconds
Hana 1.228 Seconds
Mickey 5.163 Seconds
```

Any help or simple example is much appreciated,

Thank youu

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far, what worked and what hasn't worked? As it stands, you're basically asking someone to write it all for you. By showing what you've tried we can better understand where your problem is and how we can help

Comment: I don't think message reactions have timestamps, so you'd have to have the bot create the message and then monitor the reactions through https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd

Answer (score 0):

The message object has a property called createdTimestamp, you can use that to calculate the milliseconds between the messages.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createdTimestamp